# Docker - Jenkins unable to reach sonarqube (via localhost/127.0.0.1:9000)

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

First of all, I know there are a ton of similar post on StackOverflow with regards to this issue, and I have tried the "solutions" that was provided. Which are either use the localhost IP or Sonar Docker IP as the URL in the "Configure System". But both methods does not seem to work in my case. Where did I configure wrong?

**Sonar Docker command:**

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -e SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE=true -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:latest
```

**Jenkins Docker command:**

```
docker run \
  --name jenkins-docker \
  --rm \
  --detach \
  --privileged \
  --network jenkins \
  --network-alias docker \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --publish 3000:3000 \
  --publish 2376:2376 \
  docker:dind \
  --storage-driver overlay2
```

**Docker Network**

[image]

**Configure System - The "Secret Text" contain the token I got from SonarQube**

[image]

**Global Tool Configuration**

[image]

**Pipeline script**

```
pipeline { 
    agent any 
    stages { 
        stage ('Checkout') { 
            steps { 
                git branch:'master', url: 'https://github.com/OWASP/Vulnerable-Web-Application.git' 
            } 
        } 
         
        stage('Code Quality Check via SonarQube') { 
           steps { 
               script { 
                def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube'; 
                   withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') { 
                   sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=OWSAP -Dsonar.sources=." 
                   } 
               } 
           } 
        } 
    } 
    post { 
        always { 
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: sonarQube() 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, the sonarqube url in jenkins should be `http://sonarqube:9000` since this is the DNS-name under which the jenkins-server can reach the sonarqube-server (in the docker network).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried as you have suggested, using http://sonarqube:9000 can't be reached as well

Comment: Can you verify that - the sonarqube container is running (`docker ps` should show it in `RUNNING` state) - sonarqube can be accessed from the docker host through `http://loclahost:9000` - you can ping host `sonarqube` from within the  jenkins container - you can `curl http://sonarqube:9000` from the jenkins container?

Comment: I was only able to access the sonarqube URL via localhost:9000. I tried using the IP address and the DNS, but was unable to load the sonarqube page

Comment: Yes the sonarqube container is running. But I was unable to ping sonarqube from within the jenkins container, neither can I curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `--network jenkins` while building sonarqube container.

Or donot use --network parameter, its default to use `bridge` mode for both containers

Jenkins and Sonarqube should be the same network.
Then try to use `http://172.17.0.1:9000` or `http://sonarqube:9000` if `http://localhost:9000` does not work.

Comment: Thank you. It was because of the network. thank you so much